# Filter Facebook profile pictures retrieved using Facepile

Tags: facebook, filter, facepile

I've implemented Facepile in my website and it works perfectly. It just displays the profile pictures of users who have liked my page. Now, I want to display the profile pictures of users from a particular area (Say India or Chennai). In other words, I just want to filter the profile pictures based on the location. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't filter users in facepile, you can't event get list of fanpage fan using API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/